# Creating drop down of derived fields from CSV using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, csv, python-script-tool, parameters, tool-validation

I'm trying to create a drop down menu in a Python script in ArcMap where one input is a CSV and the other input is a drop down of the headers in that CSV. Is this possible at all?

[image]

In the image above, "Candidate List" is the supplied CSV and "Candidate Field" is the field header that the user selects for the column that the data is located in. Would I have to put something in the script its self or in the update parameters?

```
with open(Candidate List, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader()
    i = reader.next()
```

Wherein I want I to be the fields for that drop down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible. You would need to use [script tool validation class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/customizing-script-tool-behavior.htm).

1. Read the .csv headers (can be done with `csv` or `pandas`, for instance).

With `csv`:

```
import csv
csv.DictReader(open(r"C:\GIS\grafiti.csv","r")).fieldnames
['FID', 'OBJECTID', 'CID', 'SqFtAprox', 'POINT_X', 'POINT_Y']
```

With `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(r"C:\GIS\grafiti.csv").columns.tolist()
['FID', 'OBJECTID', 'CID', 'SqFtAprox', 'POINT_X', 'POINT_Y']
```

2. Use `updateParameters` to set values of the needed parameter to the list of columns.

Code:

```
self.params[2].filter.list = headers
```

Please look up the help page for more examples. Another helpful answer is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247756/wildcard-for-field-in-arcpy-getparameterastext/247762#247762).

Comment: The only issue is that the CSV being input will always be different for different users, can this still be implemented?

Comment: Of course. You will be updating your .csv headers parameter list values every time a user browses to her .csv file. The list values will not be stored within the tool itself; it will be read dynamically upon every tool execution after users specifies the input .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, see below:

```
def updateParameters(self):
    if self.params[4].value and \
   (self.params[4].value.value.endswith("xls") or self.params[4].value.value.endswith("xlsx")):
    import xlrd
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(self.params[4].value.value)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    headers = [str(cell.value) for cell in sheet.row(0)]
    self.params[5].filter.list = headers
```

Comment: Hm, isn't it what I have told you to do? ;) in the question, you talk about .csv, now you are reading .xls. But glad you got something working anyways :)

Comment: It is, yes. I have it configured for both xls and csv depending on user input. I wasn't quite sure how to implement the `self.params[4]` and I wasn't aware that I had to use `self.params[4].value.value` in order to actually open the file.